# Why we need tagbits when we already have indexbit and offset?

Tags: memory-management, cpu-cache, virtual-memory

I was watching a lecture and got confused at one point when professor said that to distinguish between two addresses having same values of offset as well as index bit we need tag.Why we need tag ? for example He was explaining that both addresses can have different values .I want to know that how can value be different when we know offset and index both as it refers to exact byte location of whole word array ? isn't it ? please check the fallowing video at 3:25 .thanks .

http://youtu.be/WW-_i8LmgvE?t=3m25s

Answer (score 1):

Multiple memory locations hash to the same location in the memory cache.  The tag array serves to disambiguate which memory location's contents are stored in each cache location.  If the address in the corresponding tag array location matches the address the CPU referenced, then the cached value is from the correct memory location and can be used, otherwise the value must be retrieved from another cache or main memory.  This kind of verification is necessary for all hash table applications where the hash function is surjective, i.e. many onto one rather than one to one.

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply but I am not getting how you said "Multiple memory locations hash to the same location in the memory cache" .can you please elaborate it more or suggest some reference to read it further ? thank you !